# ienumerable update in foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

I have a code like this.

```
IEnumerable<string> imagesFileNames = FindImages(imagesFolder);

 foreach(string imageFileName in imagesFileNames)

            {
                //my code
                //IEnumerable<string> imagesFilesNames = FindImages(imagesFolder);
                // it doesn't work!!  
            }
```

Can i update the IENumerable collection in foreach loop?

Comment: Do you mean modifying a collection while being inside a foreach... And by modifying, I mean adding or removing an item from the collection?

Comment: "it doesn't work!!" -- this isn't helpful!!

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Is it lazy? :)

Comment: I don't even understand what you're _trying_ to do in this loop.  With each iteration of the loop, you attempt to completely blow away the collection and replace it with a new one.  If it "did work" it would never end.  Why are you iterating over the collection in the first place?

Comment: For the love... What do you want to do within those bracket? What do you want to perform on that collection?

Comment: You cannot change the IList/Array[]/.. which derived from IEnumerable in foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. I realized that after your comments , that's a bad idea.
And decided to change my method. I solved it with a timer with calling the 
images' names in order.

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 a++;
 imageFileName = "IMAGES\DB\"+a+".jpg"
\\\my code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to [Stackoverflow](http://www.Stackoverflow.com). You cannot change the IEnumerable your iterating over in that loop.

**It looks like you want to recursively look for files:**

```
IEnumerable<string> imagesFileNames = FindImages(imagesFolder, "*.jpg", true);

private IEnumerable<string> FindImages(string dir, string extension, bool isRecursive)
try
{
    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, extension))
            {
                imagesFileNames.Add(f);
            }
            if (isRecursive) FindImages(d,extension, true);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {    
        }
    }
}
```